# Create table form using ngFor and ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a table of played tracks in concert, but in every row I got same inputs. Also if I add a row to array they become empty. I found that i should use something like `formGroupName="{{i}}"` but it requires to make hardcode them in ts file. How to make it properly?

My project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmjtp4

Comment: Include essential parts here instead of pastebin

Comment: stackblitz would be the best

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmjtp4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routing.ts

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It makes it a little easier for us to help you if you cut out everything from the stackblitz except the minimal needed to demonstrate the issue.That makes it much easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can figure out from the code, your problem is here?

```
        <tr *ngFor="let a of repertoire;let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
          <th scope="row">{{a.id}}</th>
          <td><input type="text" formControlName="title" [(ngModel)]="repertoire[i].title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" formControlName="composer" [(ngModel)]="repertoire[i].composer"></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteMusic(a)">Usuń</button></td>
        </tr>
```

And the definition of the form displayed here is this:

```
this.repForm = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  composer: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

The above form structure is only able to hold one set of values. You need to instead define this structure as a FormArray.

I do something similar here with a set of addresses:

```
this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildAddress()])
});
```

Notice that I'm defining it as a FormBuilder array.

Then I add to that array like this:

```
  addAddress(): void {
    this.addresses.push(this.buildAddress());
  }

  buildAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      addressType: 'home',
      street1: ['', Validators.required],
      street2: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zip: ''
    });
  }
```

And access it in the HTML like this:

```
<div formArrayName="addresses"
     *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">

  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="form-group row mb-2">
      <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
             attr.for="{{'street1Id' + i}}">Street Address 1</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control"
               id="{{'street1Id' + i}}"
               type="text"
               formControlName="street1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- More here -->
  </div>
```

You can find a complete working example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final